# Adding a game to an applet from it's class name

Tags: java, security, reflection, applet, initialization

I want to make an applet so that it can be used to display a game which extends JPanel. This class will be a part of the library. So I do not know the name of the class. I had to load it dynamically. Here's my current implementation.

```
package com.gej.core;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Runs a game as an Applet by loading the class dynamically at runtime. The
 * name of the class should be specified as a parameter named game-class.
 * 
 * @author Sri Harsha Chilakapati
 */
public class GApplet extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1994280929713148311L;

    String gmname = "";

    public GApplet(String gmname) {
        this.gmname = gmname;
    }

    public GApplet() {
        gmname = "";
    }

    public void init(){
        if (gmname == null || gmname == "") {
            gmname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter game class name");
        }
        try {
            Class<?> gameClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(gmname);
            add((Game) gameClass.newInstance());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error finding class : " + gmname);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.err.println("Error loading class : " + gmname);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.err.println("Error loading class : " + gmname);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that this works well in the Applet Viewer but doesn't work in any other browser (tested on Firefox, Opera, Epiphany, Internet Explorer, Chrome). The error is it says `Applet not initialized`.

### Output of console

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
/build/buildd/icedtea-web-1.1.3/build/../plugin/icedteanp/IcedTeaNPPlugin.cc:631: thread
0xb75368e0: Error: Unknown plugin value requested.
/build/buildd/icedtea-web-1.1.3/build/../plugin/icedteanp/IcedTeaNPPlugin.cc:631: thread 
0xb75368e0: Error: Unknown plugin value requested.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:101)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarSigner.verifyJar(JarSigner.java:241)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarSigner.verifyJars(JarSigner.java:201)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$4.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1145)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$4.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1143)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.addNewJar(JNLPClassLoader.java:1143)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1043)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:712)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:672)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:884)
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.addNewJar(JNLPClassLoader.java:1143)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1043)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:712)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:672)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:884)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:101)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarSigner.verifyJar(JarSigner.java:241)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarSigner.verifyJars(JarSigner.java:201)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$4.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1145)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$4.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1143)
... 6 more
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize applet.
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:728)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:672)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:884)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gej.GApplet
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1089)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:712)
... 2 more
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gej.GApplet
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1089)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:712)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:672)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:884)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.runLoader(NetxPanel.java:109)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:380)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.run(NetxPanel.java:69)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:430)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.run(NetxPanel.java:69)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

### Update

I've managed to get rid of that by updating the plugin. Here's the new log.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission sun.java2d.opengl write)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:393)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPSecurityManager.checkPermission(JNLPSecurityManager.java:284)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:744)
at com.gej.core.Game.init(Game.java:83)
at com.gej.core.Game.<init>(Game.java:69)
at com.breakout.Breakout.<init>(Breakout.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at com.gej.core.GApplet.init(GApplet.java:38)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:436)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.run(NetxPanel.java:69)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

### Solved

This is what I had changed and it solved

```
try {
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // System doesn't support opengl
}
```

I've modified the code so that it'll be only setting the property in windowed or fullscreen mode only

Comment: As noted, my answer is completely wrong.  I cannot see anything in that code that could cause the `SecurityException` that you are seeing.  I suspect now that it might be use of an `URLClassLoader`, but until you can post complete code that shows the error, I am really just guessing.

Comment: *"I'm currently using IcedTea java plugin and it showed me a dialog error and closed. In the java console it said `SecurityException at line 19`"*  I'm guessing that was not the entire stack trace, please copy/paste **all** content in the console.  Put it as an edit to the question, rather than as a new comment.

Comment: The `add(new TestGame())` is not working either. It says `access denied for java2d.opengl.pipeline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    (java.util.PropertyPermission sun.java2d.opengl write)
```

Only a trusted applet can set the property.  Digitally sign the code.

Comment: Also when I just added a test game by using `add(new TestGame())` also gives the same error

Comment: Change all the `catch` statements to add `e.printStackTrace();`. Open the Java Console.  Copy/paste the output.

Comment: I'm currently using IcedTea java plugin and it showed me a dialog error and closed. In the java console it said `SecurityException at line 19`

Comment: I expected a `SecurityException` for reflection (in an untrusted applet), but it should have worked or shown a different error for `add(new TestGame())`..

Comment: `add(new TestGame())` didn't work either and even no error is thrown. May be I should try making the Game class extend JApplet and embedding it in JFrame for windowed mode. And I'm using ImageIO class to load images in seperate thread for my game. Could that be a cause?

Comment: *"And I'm using ImageIO class"*  That leads me to suspect that the code used above is not only not the only code involved, but is not even literally the code used for the applet!  Trying to help you without knowing the exact code, is a waste of my time.  :/

Comment: @Tom Huhh..  Thanks for the heads-up.  Although I realize you know a lot more about security than me, I had to actually test it to confirm that reflection **does** work in a sand-box. I've been laboring under that misunderstanding for a long time.  I'll leave the answer for a while so the OP can see the new comments.

Comment: @AndrewThompson To give a bit more information, untrusted accs can't use `setAccessible` and package hierarchies listed in the `package.access` security property are also unavailable. So untrusted reflection shouldn't allow access to stuff you couldn't link to anyway.

Comment: @Sri  Please let me know when you have seen the updates.  This answer should be deleted.

Comment: @AndrewThompson IcedTea plugin had gone weird and it stopped logging all the files

Comment: I have updated my answer.  @Tom Thanks for the extra info.  I suspected there were some aspects of reflection that required trust, since it is effectively a powerful tool with potentially far-ranging consequences.

Comment: To set the property I'm using this code. `
        try {
            System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // System doesn't support opengl
        }
        ` Why this would give me exception if I'm swallowing the exception???

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, it's working now. It'll only set the property in windowed or applet mode.